# Where are my inodes used (advanced, debugfs, etc)

Tags: ext4, e2fsck, debugfs

I made a copy of an ext4 volume with many errors and fscked it, before making an extensive comparison in order to make sure no data was lost in the process. since there were all kind of codings in the filenames, I decided to work by inode instead of by filename and use debugfs and md5sum to compute a control sum for every non zeroed inodes (some of them being nonzeroed but marked as free). Then I jointed the result with the list on files (and dirs, etc) by inodes, and made sure that the inner join was the same on both filesystems.

However, to my big surprise, I also found in the remain (outer join less inner join), 3 inodes which seem to have been allocated during the repair process (they were marked `used` on the `fscked` copy and not on the original and `free` on the original `errored` volume), and I can't figure out, what they are related with :

```
root:~# for F in md0p2.nomatch md0p99.nomatch  ; do grep used $F; done | sort -n | uniq -u | less
279838261 used 5e8519e3eea8bc75915e03caa75dadf9
279838289 used e43d2402bf4355df67a59ac5220711d4
279838348 used d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
root:~# egrep '279838261|279838289|279838348' md0p2.md5.saved md0p99.md5.saved 
md0p2.md5.saved:(279838261, free, 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e')
md0p2.md5.saved:(279838289, free, 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e')
md0p2.md5.saved:(279838348, free, 'a674e48d26a9c2827d6de2791b420b77')
md0p99.md5.saved:(279838261, used, '5e8519e3eea8bc75915e03caa75dadf9')
md0p99.md5.saved:(279838289, used, 'e43d2402bf4355df67a59ac5220711d4')
md0p99.md5.saved:(279838348, used, 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e')
root:~# debugfs /dev/md0p99
debugfs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
debugfs:  ncheck <279838261>
ncheck: Bad inode - <279838261>
debugfs:  ncheck <279838289>
ncheck: Bad inode - <279838289>
debugfs:  ncheck <279838348>
ncheck: Bad inode - <279838348>
debugfs:  q
```

any idea what else I could try to investigate it ?

EDIT (answer to Icarus's question) :

```
debugfs:  inode_dump <279838261>
0000  8967 075e 545e 612a 6127 db67 c53d 0ef4  .g.^T^a*a'.g.=..
0020  6c2a 636c dec3 cb60 c670 0000 6639 6639  l*cl...`.p..f9f9
0040  0000 0000 8975 9a50 6a70 6b6d 6d2f a466  .....u.Pjpkmm/.f
0060  f27f a7b0 6e6a 7663 7760 ed6a fa2d e9e0  ....njvcw`.j.-..
0100  7d6e 715d 6736 aa68 e73d bde1 632a 767b  }nq]g6.h.=..c*v{
0120  736c bf39 e477 bc08 785b 4468 252f aa69  sl.9.w..x[Dh%/.i
0140  ef72 869e 695f 665f 2d6d e370 b039 8825  .r..i_f_-m.p.9.%
0160  366c 2c72 6c7a eb70 b97f f033 6962 2a6f  6l,rlz.p...3ib*o
0200  2a20 b82c a83e eec8 7b61 3f3f 3e6e f46e  * .,.>..{a??>n.n
0220  be4f d287 2d22 2a6f 3e6b ac61 ae4b efd9  .O..-"*o>k.a.K..
0240  2560 6376 6220 ae61 f477 503f 6477 6b76  %`cvb .a.wP?dwkv
0260  6a66 ec2a aa76 5b2f 222d 3963 3e68 ac55  jf.*.v[/"-9c>h.U
0300  b73e 27c7 2562 6d6c 775a eb7e da2b 528e  .>'.%bmlwZ.~.+R.
0320  7339 6c77 6f65 bf39 8a6a c893 257c 3867  s9lwoe.9.j..%|8g
0340  386a ac7d 8b61 96b2 6739 3f3f 6536 e12a  8j.}.a..g9??e6.*
0360  cd35 a957 6e39 612c 7b24 e92e d334 ded7  .5.Wn9a,{$...4..

debugfs:  stat <279838261>
invalid inode->i_extra_isize (8234)
Inode: 279838261   Type: block special    Mode:  03611   Flags: 0x0
Generation: 1600544617    Version: 0x61ac6b3e:509a7589
User: 2142854663   Group: 871395526   Project: -638628946   Size: 711024212
File ACL: 124156513578285
Links: 0   Blockcount: 134605238057318
Fragment:  Address: 1915513910    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0xf40e3dc5:c8ee3ea8 -- Mon Aug 26 16:12:05 1963
 atime: 0x67db2761:6ef46e3e -- Wed Jun  2 11:18:25 2297
 mtime: 0x6c632a6c:3f3f617b -- Thu Dec  6 14:09:00 2435
crtime: 0x87d24fbe:6f2a222d -- Mon Mar 17 23:12:14 2042
 dtime: 0x60cbc3de:(c8ee3ea8) -- Thu Jun 17 23:51:26 2021
Size of extra inode fields: 8234
Device major/minor number: 112:106 (hex 70:6a)
debugfs:  inode_dump <279838289>
0000  7744 2a7d b82c a7b5 8b36 2c65 746e 1b14  wD*}.,...6,etn..
0020  1433 61e6 dec3 cb60 2e08 0000 237d 1529  .3a....`....#}.)
0040  0000 0000 2565 2422 0f38 3b3a 5fbb 5edf  ....%e$".8;:_.^.
0060  786c 6b71 280c 6232 2c63 bfdc af63 762c  xlkq(.b2,c...cv,
0100  4e30 4424 792b 3bad 8b60 246f 3d65 7202  N0D$y+;..`$o=er.
0120  3d10 8e4a e205 3065 772e 6628 5862 2e86  =..J..0ew.f(Xb..
0140  71ba 06c6 5768 2c6e 6106 2c3b c02d f801  q...Wh,na.,;.-..
0160  2425 3e64 2422 4028 72c1 76a3 3e27 7a2c  $%>d$"@(r.v.>'z,
0200  6e2e 621d 252c f369 a66a e56e 2d79 7061  n.b.%,.i.j.n-ypa
0220  1c3e 3d34 20a9 6d20 7f5f 605f 7941 627e  .>=4 .m ._`_yAb~
0240  cc66 e943 8d62 6376 6a22 4e29 3882 7398  .f.C.bcvj"N)8.s.
0260  67af 6a2c 766a 6a1b 7e67 b668 59c3 7e76  g.j,vjj.~g.hY.~v
0300  716d 7146 1e36 4a61 80b8 223f 643f 6146  qmqF.6Ja.."?d?aF
0320  346d 2672 14a4 6f2a 5160 3805 6f63 8f65  4m&r..o*Q`8.oc.e
0340  e32a 7e77 6766 2d0c 3375 0b6f 6799 7e68  .*~wgf-.3u.og.~h
0360  6e23 3e05 6d60 6847 0825 562a 676a 254e  n#>.m`hG.%V*gj%N

debugfs:  stat <279838289>
invalid inode->i_extra_isize (11886)
Inode: 279838289   Type: directory    Mode:  02167   Flags: 0x0
Generation: 1848404055    Version: 0x5f605f7f:22246525
User: -1049461462   Group: -1552545746   Project: 2120368505   Size: -1247335240
File ACL: 44256335758945
Links: 0   Blockcount: 37538703441187
Fragment:  Address: 1681794340    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x141b6e74:69f32c25 -- Fri Oct 16 18:36:04 2116
 atime: 0x652c368b:6170792d -- Thu Nov 22 02:27:39 2159
 mtime: 0xe6613314:6ee56aa6 -- Fri Aug  1 15:37:24 2228
crtime: 0x343d3e1c:206da920 -- Thu Oct  9 22:27:08 1997
 dtime: 0x60cbc3de:(69f32c25) -- Mon Jul 25 06:19:42 2157
Size of extra inode fields: 11886
BLOCKS:
(0):976959503, (1):3747527519, (2):1902865528, (3):845286440, (4):3703530284, (5):745956271, (6):608448590, (7):2906336121, 
[...]
(1033):3110968555, (1034):1757067253, (1035):264071090, (DIND):2251186776, (TIND):3322329713
TOTAL: 1038

debugfs:  inode_dump <279838348>
0000  e17b 1d1a 0000 0000 644c 5977 c847 5cd8  .{......dLYw.G\.
0020  6a2a 6466 da5f cc60 f122 0000 0000 0000  j*df._.`."......
0040  0000 0000 f020 8cb1 3076 6776 7648 5d24  ..... ..0vgvvH]$
0060  ee73 a2ee 7d6e 715d 4270 1d74 f561 e55d  .s..}nq]Bp.t.a.]
0100  7f7d 7267 2d53 5d70 e57c 150e 6765 7667  .}rg-S]p.|..gevg
0120  3e5c 466a 1f7a 55fb 652c 632b 784c 5276  >\Fj.zU.e,c+xLRv
0140  5b6c 1462 636d 712c 0000 0000 0000 0000  [l.bcmq,........
0160  4160 2b79 0000 4124 b22d c781 6567 766b  A`+y..A$.-..egvk
0200  1c00 1b65 e073 a2e7 7961 7677 7154 1363  ...e.s..yavwqT.c
0220  bd7a faca 414e 2a63 2f59 1f66 e65e 5eb1  .z..AN*c/Y.f.^^.
0240  3b28 2333 2a47 0863 b37a 1b0c 7c2c 602c  ;(#3*G.c.z..|,`,
0260  495e 1f62 b57e 5a3a 626b 6c2a 6116 572d  I^.b.~Z:bkl*a.W-
0300  c438 54d8 7f6c 6b71 2d68 4165 e674 46ad  .8T..lkq-hAe.tF.
0320  2d22 6574 6949 6c4f f338 6db0 3b59 2e66  -"etiIlO.8m.;Y.f
0340  580b 6e28 d223 c39d 6a2d 7f2e 7752 5a77  X.n(.#..j-..wRZw
0360  8672 fdfd 2366 2c5b 6013 4872 cf7d aec9  .r..#f,[`.Hr.}..

debugfs:  stat <279838348>
debugfs:  Inode: 279838348   Type: bad type    Mode:  05741   Flags: 0x0
Generation: 745631075    Version: 0x661f592f:b18c20f0
User: 766646813   Group: -2117655823   Size: 0
File ACL: 39861591474176
Links: 0   Blockcount: 0
Fragment:  Address: 2032885825    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0xd85c47c8:e7a273e0 -- Sat Dec  4 19:24:08 1948
 atime: 0x77594c64:63135471 -- Fri Jul 21 14:17:40 2169
 mtime: 0x66642a6a:77766179 -- Tue Jul 15 18:23:06 2160
crtime: 0xcafa7abd:632a4e41 -- Mon Nov 29 13:04:13 2077
 dtime: 0x60cc5fda:(e7a273e0) -- Fri Jun 18 10:56:58 2021
Size of extra inode fields: 28
BLOCKS:
(0):1986491952, (1):610093174, (2):4003623918, (3):1567714941, (4):1948086338, (5):1575313909, (6):1735556479, (7):1885164333, 
[...]
(306179):592454480, (306180):4793153, (306181):25299970, (306182):2013266074, (306183):394777, (TIND):1645505627, (DIND):3120627712
TOTAL: 3082
```

Comment: What is the type of the inode (directory, file, fifo ...)? I would use `inode_dump <279838201>` and `stat`.

Comment: @Icarus : I checked and added the reply in the post

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. The inodes are clearly not valid, and I can't recognize any structure in them. My immediate thought is this is probably a bug in fsck if it created them - I don't think I can help any more.